# Underlining several columns in a table with a single line

Tags: tables, underline

Here is a table in LaTeX where I have underlined "Main number" and "Subnumber":

[image]

Source:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \underline{Main number} & \underline{Subnumber} & Name \\
  \hline
  1 & 1 & Bob \\
  1 & 2 & Bob \\
  2 & 1 & Liz \\
  2 & 3 & Sam \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Now I'd like to use a single line to underline both columns, something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I would also like a solution that handles this case, where I just changed "Main number" to "Big number", causing the underlines to be drawn on different levels:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `\underline{Main number}`, I added `\rlap{\underline{~~~~}}`, which lays an underline of 4 spaces to the right, while taking up no net space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \underline{Main number}\rlap{\underline{~~~~}} & \underline{Subnumber} & Name \\
  \hline
  1 & 1 & Bob \\
  1 & 2 & Bob \\
  2 & 1 & Liz \\
  2 & 3 & Sam \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To handle cases where one of the headers has a descender, you need to add a `\vphantom` descender to the other item as well as the `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\pg{\vphantom{g}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \underline{Big number}\rlap{\underline{\pg~~~~}} & \underline{Subnumber\pg} & Name \\[2pt]
  \hline
  1 & 1 & Bob \\
  1 & 2 & Bob \\
  2 & 1 & Liz \\
  2 & 3 & Sam \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works well, at least until I change "Main number" to "Big number", causing the lines to be drawn on different levels! (See edit.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy See my addendum.

Answer (score 1):

There is, yes, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you insist, you can easily do that with `pstricks`. To compile pstricks code with `pdflatex`, use the compiler switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) and load `auto-pst-pdf`. Alternatively, compile with `xelatex`.

Comment aside: to have nicely intersecting horizontal and vertical lines in tables, load the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \pnode[0,-0.5ex]{B}Main number &Subnumber\pnode[0,-0.5ex]{E} & Name \\
  \hline
  1 & 1 & Bob \\
  1 & 2 & Bob \\
  2 & 1 & Liz \\
  2 & 3 & Sam \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\ncline[linewidth=\arrayrulewidth]{B}{E}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pstricks` and `write18`??  Isn't that like using a sledgehammer to swat a fly?

Comment: It avoids `latex -> dvi -> ps -> pdf`, that all. `xelatex` would work as well, but many people don't use it.